# is there a way to expire only the hash key(subkey) in redis through java in hashoperation

Tags: java, redis

I have a situation where its needed to expire only hash key of a data set in redis. is there a way to do it through java with hashoperation.
I know redis can only support the key expiry not hashkey(subkey with value). But is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis Doesn't support such operation

You can use regular hash for values and sorted set to handle expirations, so using such hash become something like this:

```
keys = ZRANGEBYSCORE(zkey, 0, now)
if keys.size>0
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE(zkey, 0, now)
HDEL(hkey, *keys)
end
val = HGET(hkey, key)
```

This way every getting will clean up the hash from expired keys. Alternatively cleaning up could be done every few seconds/minutes by background task